# Вопросы по Keras model sequential

Tags: python, нейронные-сети, keras

Есть несколько вопросов, буду рада получить ответы. Вот мой код:

```
from tensorflow.python.keras.datasets import mnist
from tensorflow.python.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.python.keras import utils
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.misc import toimage
import pandas as pd
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout
from keras import optimizers
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping, ModelCheckpoint 
import keras
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from keras.utils import plot_model

data = pd.read_excel('c:/users/----/anaconda3/17/lada2.xls', header=None)
X, Y = np.array(data[[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]]), np.array(data[11])

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size = 0.3, random_state = None)
N, d = X.shape

epochs=400
batch_size=1000
dense1=26 
dense2=34 
dropout1=99
dropout2=99
dropout3=99

input_dim=10

activation1='relu'                    
activation2='softsign'
activation3='selu'

model = Sequential()

model.add(Dense(dense1, input_dim=input_dim))
model.add(Dropout(dropout1))
model.add(Dense(dense2, activation=activation2))
model.add(Dropout(dropout2))
model.add(Dense(1, activation=activation3))
model.add(Dropout(dropout3))
model.compile(loss="mean_squared_error", optimizer="Adam", metrics=["accuracy"])

history = model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=batch_size, epochs=epochs, validation_split=0.3, verbose=2)

print(history.history.keys())
plt.plot(history.history['acc'], label='Аккуратность на обучающем наборе')
#plt.plot(history.history['val_loss'], label='ошибка на проверочном наборе')

plt.plot(history.history['val_acc'], label='Аккуратность на проверочном наборе')
plt.xlabel('Эпоха обучения')
plt.ylabel('Аккуратность')
plt.legend()
model.save('c:/users/----/anaconda3/17/00000000')
print(history.history['val_acc'][-1])
score= model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, batch_size=batch_size)
print('1', score[1])
model.summary()
```

Вопросы следующие:

1. Есть разделение на обучающую и тестовую выборку, я в данном примере использую train_test_split на 30% и 70%.
   Также есть параметр validation_split=0.3 который в свою очередь также разделяет на обучающую и тестовую выборку. Я хочу узнать, как именно лучше применять эти две функции вместе и что за что отвечает?
2. Также есть два значения на выходе - score[1] и history.history['val_acc'][-1] - какой из этих параметров отражает в действительности заданный Loss на тестовых данных? И на каких именно тестовых данных (train_test_split или validation_split)?
3. Как применять данный код для задач регрессии? При указании столбца не с бинарными ответами для учителя, а конкретные значения, которые необходимо предсказать, Loss MSE указывает совсем другие значения, чем при бинарных ответах (намного ниже процент). Как можно перестроить данный код для задач регрессии?
4. Для оптимизации гиперпараметров я использую циклы по 1. эпохам; 2. batch_size; 3. dense1; 4. dense2; 5. dropout1; 6. dropout2; 7. dropout3; 8. activation1; 9. activation2; 10. activation3; 11. loss; 12 optimizer.
   Как можно оптимизировать поиск лучшей структуры модели и гиперпараметров?

Спасибо!

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос так, чтобы он описывал конкретную проблему с достаточной детализацией для определения адекватного ответа. Не задавайте сразу несколько вопросов. См. [«Как задать хороший вопрос?»](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) для прояснения ситуации.

Comment: Советую вам открыть четыре отдельных вопроса...